# Changing the text color with Javascript depending on the number

Tags: javascript

I need to change the text color to red if the answer is '7' and to green if it's '13' or '24'. I've tried several different things but I can't seem to get it to work. I don't know if someone knows what I'm doing wrong, but any help would be appreciated.

```js
do {
  var luckyNumber = prompt('What is your lucky number?', "");
  luckyNumber = parseInt(luckyNumber, 10);
} while (isNaN(luckyNumber));


if (luckyNumber == 7) {
  document.write("<p>Hey, 7 is my lucky number too!</p>").style.color = "red";
} else
if (luckyNumber == 13 || luckyNumber == 24) {
  document.write("<p>Wooh. " + luckyNumber + "? That's an unlucky number!</p>").style.color = "green";
} else {
  document.write("<p>The number " + luckyNumber + " is lucky for you!</p>");
}
```

Comment: `document.write()` doesn't return an element, so you can't just assign style to it.  The easiest way to modify what you have there is simply put `document.write("<p style='color:red'>...etc.`

Comment: The problem is that `document.write()` does not return the DOM element. By the way, don't use `document.write`.

Comment: @meskobalazs There's no reason to blanket state "don't use document.write".  You don't know anything about the OP's reasoning so don't assume they're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the color in the html tag by adding "style='color:(color)'"
you can use something like this

```js
<script>
var luckyNumber = 7;
if (luckyNumber == 7) {
        document.write("<p style='color:red'>Hey, 7 is my lucky number too!</p>");
    } else if (luckyNumber == 13 || luckyNumber == 24) {
        document.write("<p style='color:green'>Wooh. " + luckyNumber + "? That's an unlucky number!</p>");
    } else {
        document.write("<p>The number " + luckyNumber + " is lucky for you!</p>");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because `document.write()` doesn't return an element which you can call `style.color` on. This is why you see the error in the console. You should also avoid the use of `document.write` anyway as it's extremely bad practice.

Instead, use `document.createElement()` to add your new elements to the DOM. From there you can simply add classes to them which apply the required colours through CSS rules. Something like this:

```js
do {
  var luckyNumber = parseInt(prompt('What is your lucky number?', ""), 10);
} while (isNaN(luckyNumber));

var p = document.createElement('p');
document.body.appendChild(p);

if (luckyNumber == 7) {
  p.textContent = 'Hey, 7 is my lucky number too!';
  p.classList.add('red');
} else
if (luckyNumber == 13 || luckyNumber == 24) {
  p.textContent = `Wooh. ${luckyNumber}? That's an unlucky number!`;
  p.classList.add('green');
} else {
  p.textContent = `The number ${luckyNumber} is lucky for you!`;
}
```

```css
.red { color: #C00; }
.green { color: #0C0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using an inline style attribute instead?

```js
do {
  var luckyNumber = prompt('What is your lucky number?',"");
  luckyNumber = parseInt(luckyNumber, 10);
} while (isNaN(luckyNumber));

if (luckyNumber == 7) {
  document.write("<p style='color:red;'>Hey, 7 is my lucky number too!</p>");
} else if (luckyNumber == 13 || luckyNumber == 24) {
  document.write("<p style='color:green;'>Wooh. " + luckyNumber + "? That's an unlucky number!</p>");
} else {
  document.write("<p>The number " + luckyNumber + " is lucky for you!</p>");
}
```